# Showing loading indicator while writing data to Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question regarding the fact, that i cant seem to figure out how to show a loader when updating firestore.

I have provided this following example, but dont mind the things i have used in the example. The point is, that I cant seem to figure out how to show a loading indicator until all creations or updates are completely finished.

If i try to setstate before and after the firestore call, the spinner will only appear in 1 second, since the actual call is running in the background (asynchronously i think) when it is updating the firestore.

Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks in advance.

```
array.forEach(itemInArray => {
db.where(test, '==', itemInArray.test )get()
  .then((result) => {
    // try to update doc first
    db.doc(result.docs[0].id).update({
      test: 'test'
    });
  })
  // update successfull
  .then(() => console.log('Document exists! We have updated the current one'))
  // If the update failed, we create new doc
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Created document);
    db.doc().set({
      test: 'test'
    });
  });
```

});

Comment: Are you asking how to notify the browser (or any client) that a database operation was finished?

Comment: The client. I want to show a spinner while updating the database.

Comment: How do you communicate with the server? REST api? Websocket? Fire signals?

Comment: The following REST API https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api

Comment: Ah, I see. Why do you think that firestore takes longer to update? It's very reasonable that the 1 second your spinner appears, is mostly message travel time.

Comment: Yeah, but let's say I have a lot of documents that needs to created. This process of creating the actual documents in the firestore, takes time. If the user happen to refresh the page, the creation would stop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183962/discussion-between-kraylog-and-oliver-juhl).

Answer (score 1):

As we discussed in the chat, if your database operations need to be sequential, you could do something like this:

```
showSpinner();
updateFirstThing()
  .then(() => updateSecondThing())
  .then(() => updateThirdThing())
  .catch(err => handlerError(err))
  .finally(() => hideSpinner());
```

If some of the operations can be parallel, you'd need to consider using `Promise.all` to make sure the spinner is hidden when all of the promises are fulfilled (or there was an error).